# TextField issue when its text reaches the full width of the text field

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-textinputfield

This is the code below, i've checked all the possibilities i could't find the solution.
Whenever the textField text is filled to its end the issue appears [After the field is filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m70AE.png), other wise it looks fine [Before the field gets filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPQJP.png), also i've attached the image with my draft please check it out, anyone please get me out of this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kancerx/infrastructure/utils/supporting_files/colors.dart';
import 'package:kancerx/presentation/common_widget/textform_field.dart';
import 'package:kancerx/presentation/theme/app_theme.dart';

class CustomSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String) onTextChanges;

  const CustomSearchBar({super.key, required this.onTextChanges});

  @override
  State<CustomSearchBar> createState() => _CustomSearchBarState();
}

class _CustomSearchBarState extends State<CustomSearchBar> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool isEmptyText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 60,
      color: ColorsManager.primaryVariant,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 5, left: isEmptyText ? 26 : 0),
                        child: TextField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            if (text.length > 3) {
                              widget.onTextChanges(text);
                            }
                            setState(() {
                              isEmptyText = text.isEmpty;
                            });
                          },
                          style: AppTheme.basicTheme.textTheme.bodyMedium
                              ?.copyWith(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          controller: searchController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: !isEmptyText,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              searchController.text = "";
                              isEmptyText = true;
                            });
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                if (isEmptyText)
                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (isEmptyText)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        "Search",
                        style: AppTheme.basicTheme.textTheme.bodyMedium
                            ?.copyWith(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text field have some useful properties like hintText, suffixIcon, etc. So, you can use these features instead of place them by using flutter layout components. I refactored your widget then your problem is solved. Also, I left notes about features as comment lines.

```
class CustomSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String) onTextChanges;

  const CustomSearchBar({super.key, required this.onTextChanges});

  @override
  State<CustomSearchBar> createState() => _CustomSearchBarState();
}

class _CustomSearchBarState extends State<CustomSearchBar> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool isEmptyText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 60,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    if (text.length > 3) {
                      widget.onTextChanges(text);
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      isEmptyText = text.isEmpty;
                    });
                  },

                  // use Theme.of(context) to get current theme of your app
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodyMedium
                      ?.copyWith(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    focusColor: Colors.transparent,

                    // use contentPadding property to add padding for entered text
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 6,
                      left: 8,
                    ),

                    // use hint text property for placeholder
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyMedium
                        ?.copyWith(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),

                    // use prefix or prefixIcon property for icon on left of text field
                    prefixIcon: isEmptyText
                        ? const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey)
                        : null,

                    // use suffix or suffixIcon property for icon on right of text field
                    suffixIcon: isEmptyText
                        ? null
                        : IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                searchController.text = "";
                                isEmptyText = true;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                  ),
                  controller: searchController,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works nice!, Thank you for the response, here after i'll follow the properties of widgets itself and then i understood your comments :).

Answer (score 0):

Faruk's answer is right, but if you don't want to refactor all the widget, just placed de padding inside de TextField decoration's.

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
            color: Colors.indigo,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            // REMOVE THE CONTAINER PARENT
                            child: TextField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                              onChanged: (text) {
                                if (text.length > 3) {
                                  widget.onTextChanges(text);
                                }
                                setState(() {
                                  isEmptyText = text.isEmpty;
                                });
                              },
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 5, left: isEmptyText ? 26 : 0)),  // AND PLACE THE PADDING  HERE
                              controller: searchController,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: !isEmptyText,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    searchController.text = "";
                                    isEmptyText = true;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon:
                                    const Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.grey),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      if (isEmptyText)
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      if (isEmptyText)
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                            child: Text(
                              "Search",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```